# Transfer software license/registration keys to a new Mac

Tags: macos, migration, license

Where does OS X store license/registration keys for apps? Is there any way these can be moved over to a new Mac?

[Context: I did a clean install upgrade from OS X Mavericks to Yosemite. I would like to transfer the license keys of specific apps from my previous installation (which was backed up using a disk cloner) to the new one.]

Comment: You should have a look at `~/Library/Application Support` and `~/Library/Preferences`. Most programs stores there their apps licenses and preferences. But, not all, there is no easy rule for want you want.

Answer (score 2):

There are a lot methods used and places where licenses and registration keys are stored:

1. User specific:

   ```
   ~/
   ~/Library/Application Support/Application or domain
   ~/Library/Preferences
   ```

   This might be plist files, invisible .domain.plist and .random.plist files or files and folders containing files with random names. Also specific 'License'-files exist.
2. Machine specific:

   ```
   /Library/Application Support/Application or domain
   /Library/Preferences
   ```

   This might be domain.plist or randomly named files, invisible .domain.plist and .random.plist files or files and folders containing files with random names. Also special 'License'-files exist.
   Some licenses are bound to specific properties of the host (e.g. MAC-address) and can't be moved straight to a new Mac (e.g. iPartition)
3. Disk specific

   Some Applications use unused/unvisible parts of partitions to store registrations. Also thumb-drives are used.

Some application even require to deactivate a registration before doing a new or clean install (AFAIR a lot of Adobe apps/suites)